# Logging in Azure from a Spark Java application

Tags: java, azure, logging, log4j2, azure-hdinsight

We are trying to develop a spark java application in Azure HDInsight linux cluster. We have been able to submit the application through Livy and it is working fine.

The problem we are facing, is related to logging. How can we use the log4j here, because if we use RollingFileAppender then we have to put the path of the output .log file. In our case then we have to write the log in the blob storage. But we think normal logging is not going to work.

We have found some logging mechanism provided by Azure itself through Azureinsights but all of them are made for web project I guess and is not working from our java application.

May you please help me here how we can implement application logging from a spark java application? May be in future people from the organization may think to use Splunk like tools to work on the logs.

Looking forward to your help.

Thanks,
Shamik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding, I think you want to write logs in the blob storage or HDFS based on Blob Storage.

So for logging into the container of blob storage, my suggestion is that you can try to use the third-party appender for `log4j`, such as [AzureLogAppender](https://github.com/elastacloud/AzureLogAppender). Or the other way for logging into the table storage is that using these appenders for `log4j`, such as [log4j-azure](https://github.com/saksham/log4j-azure) and [azure-log4j](https://github.com/JMayrbaeurl/azure-log4j).

If you want to write logs into HDFS on Azure, there are two ways as below.

1. You can refer to the [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage/) to write a custom appender for log4j.
2. Using [Apache Flume appender for Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#FlumeAppender) to send logs to Flume which writes to HDFS, that you can refer to the [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bigdatasupport/2014/03/18/using-apache-flume-with-hdinsight/) to know how to use Flume with Azure HDInsight.

Comment: Thank you. I checked with AzureLogAppender but I checked that the logs are not getting generated. Will try other options and post the result.

Comment: I think AzureLogAppender is working properly but the problem is when I am submitting the Spark job through Livy in yarn cluster the application specific log4j is not getting used. Is there any way to so? I checked with PropertyConfigurator.configure() method but the application specific log4j is not getting picked up.

Comment: @Shamik. There are two ways. 1. Upload the jar files on the cluster storage associated with the cluster. You can use AzCopy, a command line utility, to do so. Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-apache-spark-livy-rest-interface/#submit-a-batch-job-the-cluster. 2. basically both Java and Scala applications are packaged into a .jar file which can be submitted via LIvy APIs.